# Maximim/minimum of a critical point that is a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For example, $x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$. We get $y = -x$ as a critical point. Usually I get a solid number and plug it into the original function to see if it's a negative or positive value to determine if it's a max or min. But in this case, we don't have that, so I have no idea what to do.

Comment: hint: if the "critical point" is a set of points, shouldn't the minimum be too?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the hint. What is special about the minimum here, and how do you know it exists?

Comment: If you were to graph it on the complex plane, then the minimum is a set of points. See the answer below though, it's very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea you have is essentially correct.

$$\nabla f(x,y)=[2x+2y,2y+2x]^t$$

We set this to zero and get that indeed $y=-x$. 
And the hessian is

$$H(x,y) = (2,2;2,2)$$
 Because the Hessian is (strictly) positive definite (has positive eigenvalues) it is the case that this function is convex, so any minimizer is a global minimizer.

In particular, let's plug this back in the original problem, then

$$f(x,y=-x)= x^2+x^2-2x^2 = 0$$

So there is no maximum but the minimum is zero for $any$ $(x,y)$ such that $y=-x$.